Unable to configure custom java toolchain with bazel
I'm trying to use custom zulu jdk java toolchain with bazel but haven't been successful. I must admit I'm not very familiar with Java and hence not really sure what's missing.
Here's the implementation details:
MODULE.bazel
...

bazel_dep(name = "bazel_skylib", version = "1.6.1")
bazel_dep(name = "rules_java", version = "7.6.1")

bazel_dep(name = "one_jdk")
local_path_override(
    module_name = "one_jdk",
    path = "one_jdk",
)

one_jdk = use_extension("@one_jdk//one_jdk.bzl", "one_jdk")

one_jdk.remote(
    name = "zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64",
    sha256 = "****",
    strip_prefix = "****",
    url = "****",
    arch = "x86_64",
    os = "macos",
)

one_jdk.remote(
    name = "zulu_basic_jdk_macos_aarch64",
    sha256 = "****",
    strip_prefix = "****",
    url = "*****",
    arch = "aarch64",
    os = "macos",
)

use_repo(one_jdk, "zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64", "zulu_basic_jdk_macos_aarch64")

register_toolchains(
    "@one_jdk//toolchains:zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64_toolchain",
    "@one_jdk//toolchains:zulu_basic_jdk_macos_aarch64_toolchain",
)

...

one_jdk/MODULE.bazel
module(
    name = "one_jdk",
    version = "1.0.0",
    bazel_compatibility = [">=7.0.0"],
    compatibility_level = 0,
)

bazel_dep(name = "bazel_skylib", version = "1.6.1")
bazel_dep(name = "rules_java", version = "7.6.1")
bazel_dep(name = "platforms", version = "0.0.8")

one_jdk/one_jdk.bzl
load("@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:remote_java_repository.bzl", "remote_java_repository")

def _one_jdk_impl(ctx):
    repositories = []
    for name, url, sha256, strip_prefix, os, arch in ctx.attr.jdk_repositories:
        repo = remote_java_repository(
            name = name,
            urls = [url],
            sha256 = sha256,
            strip_prefix = strip_prefix,
            target_compatible_with = [
                "@platforms//os:" + os,
                "@platforms//cpu:" + arch,
            ],
        )

        repositories.append(repo)
    return repositories

one_jdk = module_extension(
    implementation = _one_jdk_impl,
    tag_classes = {
        "remote": tag_class(
            attrs = {
                "name": attr.string(mandatory = True),
                "url": attr.string(mandatory = True),
                "sha256": attr.string(mandatory = True),
                "strip_prefix": attr.string(mandatory = True),
                "os": attr.string(mandatory = True),
                "arch": attr.string(mandatory = True),
            },
        ),
    },
)

one_jdk/toolchains/BUILD
load("@rules_java//java:defs.bzl", "java_runtime", "java_toolchain")

# macOS x86_64

java_runtime(
    name = "zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64_runtime",
    java_home = "@zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64//:jdk",
    java = "@zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64//:jdk/bin/java",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

java_toolchain(
    name = "zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64_toolchain_def",
    source_version = "21",
    target_version = "21",
    java_runtime = ":zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64_runtime",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    javabuilder = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:javabuilder"],
    ijar = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:ijar"],
    singlejar = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:singlejar"],
    genclass = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:genclass"],
)

toolchain(
    name = "zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64_toolchain",
    exec_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:macos",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
    ],
    target_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:macos",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
    ],
    toolchain = ":zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64_toolchain_def",
    toolchain_type = "@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:toolchain_type",
)

# macOS ARM64

java_runtime(
    name = "zulu_basic_jdk_macos_aarch64_runtime",
    java_home = "@zulu_basic_jdk_macos_aarch64//:jdk",
    java = "@zulu_basic_jdk_macos_aarch64//:jdk/bin/java",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

java_toolchain(
    name = "zulu_basic_jdk_macos_aarch64_toolchain_def",
    source_version = "21",
    target_version = "21",
    java_runtime = ":zulu_basic_jdk_macos_aarch64_runtime",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    javabuilder = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:javabuilder"],
    ijar = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:ijar"],
    singlejar = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:singlejar"],
    genclass = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:genclass"],
)

toolchain(
    name = "zulu_basic_jdk_macos_aarch64_toolchain",
    exec_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:macos",
        "@platforms//cpu:arm64",
    ],
    target_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:macos",
        "@platforms//cpu:arm64",
    ],
    toolchain = ":zulu_basic_jdk_macos_aarch64_toolchain_def",
    toolchain_type = "@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:toolchain_type",
)


Trying to run any bazel action that would need the toolchain is either failing due to it not using the custom toolchain or due to some toolchain resolution issue.
Here are a few:
1.
bazelisk build //:print_java_home --java_runtime_version=21 --java_language_version=21
INFO: Invocation ID: 0cf34a55-e1e9-4661-9050-cf573f616bc2
WARNING: Build option --toolchain_resolution_debug has changed, discarding analysis cache (this can be expensive, see https://bazel.build/advanced/performance/iteration-speed).
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_***/****/external/rules_python~/python/private/bzlmod/python.bzl:46:10: WARNING: Ignoring toolchain 'python_3_11' from module 'rules_python': Toolchain 'python_3_11' from module 'rules_android' already registered Python version 3.11 and has precedence
ERROR: no such package '@@[unknown repo 'zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64' requested from @@one_jdk~]//': The repository '@@[unknown repo 'zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64' requested from @@one_jdk~]' could not be resolved: No repository visible as '@zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64' from repository '@@one_jdk~'
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_***/***/external/one_jdk~/toolchains/BUILD:5:13: no such package '@@[unknown repo 'zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64' requested from @@one_jdk~]//': The repository '@@[unknown repo 'zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64' requested from @@one_jdk~]' could not be resolved: No repository visible as '@zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64' from repository '@@one_jdk~' and referenced by '@@one_jdk~//toolchains:zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64_runtime'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:print_java_home' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed




bazelisk build //:print_java_home --java_runtime_version=21 --java_language_version=21 --toolchain_resolution_debug='@@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:runtime_toolchain_type'
INFO: Invocation ID: aabb234d-cacf-4e6f-8e9e-849e75f2089e
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_****/****/external/rules_python~/python/private/bzlmod/python.bzl:46:10: WARNING: Ignoring toolchain 'python_3_11' from module 'rules_python': Toolchain 'python_3_11' from module 'rules_android' already registered Python version 3.11 and has precedence
INFO: ToolchainResolution: Performing resolution of @@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:runtime_toolchain_type for target platform @@platforms//host:host
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~local_jdk//:jdk; mismatching config settings: local_jdk_name_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remote_jdk8_linux//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remote_jdk8_linux_aarch64//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remote_jdk8_linux_s390x//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remote_jdk8_macos//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remote_jdk8_macos_aarch64//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remote_jdk8_windows//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk11_linux//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk11_linux_aarch64//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk11_linux_ppc64le//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk11_linux_s390x//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk11_macos//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk11_macos_aarch64//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk11_win//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk11_win_arm64//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk17_linux//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk17_linux_aarch64//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk17_linux_ppc64le//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk17_linux_s390x//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk17_macos//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk17_macos_aarch64//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk17_win//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk17_win_arm64//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk21_linux//:jdk; mismatching values: linux
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk21_linux_aarch64//:jdk; mismatching values: linux, aarch64
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk21_linux_ppc64le//:jdk; mismatching values: linux, ppc
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk21_linux_s390x//:jdk; mismatching values: linux, s390x
      ToolchainResolution:   Toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk21_macos//:jdk is compatible with target plaform, searching for execution platforms:
      ToolchainResolution:     Compatible execution platform @@platforms//host:host
      ToolchainResolution:   All execution platforms have been assigned a @@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:runtime_toolchain_type toolchain, stopping
      ToolchainResolution: Recap of selected @@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:runtime_toolchain_type toolchains for target platform @@platforms//host:host:
      ToolchainResolution:   Selected @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk21_macos//:jdk to run on execution platform @@platforms//host:host
INFO: ToolchainResolution: Target platform @@platforms//host:host: Selected execution platform @@platforms//host:host, type @@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:runtime_toolchain_type -> toolchain @@rules_java~~toolchains~remotejdk21_macos//:jdk
ERROR: no such package '@@[unknown repo 'zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64' requested from @@one_jdk~]//': The repository '@@[unknown repo 'zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64' requested from @@one_jdk~]' could not be resolved: No repository visible as '@zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64' from repository '@@one_jdk~'
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_***/****/external/one_jdk~/toolchains/BUILD:5:13: no such package '@@[unknown repo 'zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64' requested from @@one_jdk~]//': The repository '@@[unknown repo 'zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64' requested from @@one_jdk~]' could not be resolved: No repository visible as '@zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64' from repository '@@one_jdk~' and referenced by '@@one_jdk~//toolchains:zulu_basic_jdk_macos_x64_runtime'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:print_java_home' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.669s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully

Appreciate any help.
